# Python3 Error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop

```
def index_of_smallest(list_nums):
   i = []
   if len(list_nums) == 0:
      return -1
   for i in range(len(list_nums[i] - 1)):
      if i[i] < i[i+1]:
         smallest = i[i]
   return smallest
```

Trying to write a general function that returns the index of the smallest number in a given list or return -1 if the list is empty but I am getting an error that states: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

I know there are much easier methods for this, including the using the min method but I want to achieve this using the for loop method
Any guidance would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be to use the `list` object's `.index()` method

```
def index_of_smallest(list_nums):
    if not(list_nums):
        return -1
    else:
        return list_nums.index(min(list_nums))
```

Usage:

```
>> index_of_smallest( [1,2,3,0,5,9] )
   # 3

>> index_of_smallest( [] )
   # -1
```

### Other Remarks

Your error, is due to poor namespace management. Generally you should avoid using non-descriptive variables such as `i`, due to the fact that they do not help us understand the code, and are too easy to accidentally misuse.

in `...range(len(list_nums[i]...` you are indexing the list, `list_nums` with another `list`, which is raising the `TypeError`. Not sure what you are trying to do there sorry.

Further below, you use `i[i]` which, if it works, is very confusing. Despite this, using single character variables for iterators is common, but only for those who's scope is limited to a very narrow `for` loop or list comprehension.

See [this discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71710/using-single-characters-for-variable-names-in-loops-exceptions)

Answer (score -1):

An easier solution could be:

```
def index_of_smallest(list_nums):
    if(list_nums):
        return list_nums.index(min(list_nums))
else:
    return -1
```

**What is does:** If list is empty then return -1 (*else part*), else it will find the minimum in the given list (*min(list_nums)*) and then find the index of the minimum element in the list(*list_nums.index(min(list_nums))*)

Comment: 1. You don't need brackets with the if. 2. You can shorten your code to `return int(bool(list_nums)) and list_nums.index(min(list_nums))` and you can lookup what that does. 3. I prefer `from operator import itemgetter; print(min(enumerate([1, 2, 3]), key=itemgetter(1))[0])` which is effectively numpy's `argmin` function. Sincerely, your junior from PESIT to whom you once "showed off" your weak python skills. Oh, and your indentation is wrong. I've downvoted your answer because it'll throw a SyntaxError.